# What is the purpose of directories defined by TestContext?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, testcontext

These are the (non-deprecated) directories defined in `TestContext` class and [their respective definitions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestContext%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework).

`DeploymentDirectory`

- Gets the directory for files deployed for the test run. This property typically contains a subdirectory of *TestRunDirectory*.

`ResultsDirectory`

- Gets the top-level directory that contains test results and test result directories for the test run. This is typically a subdirectory of *TestRunDirectory*.

`TestResultsDirectory`

- Gets the directory for the test result files.

`TestRunDirectory`

- Gets the top-level directory for the test run that contains deployed files and result files.

`TestRunResultsDirectory`

- Gets the top-level directory for the test run result files. This property typically contains a subdirectory of *ResultsDirectory*.

I find them quite ambiguous. Is there some solid example usage for each directory? E.g. if I were to test file I/O would any of those be OK if I wanted to create a temporary *lorem ipsum* file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your question I have gathered information from a few sources:

- [What’s in the TestResults directory?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475.aspx#Anchor_6) in [How to: Deploy Files for Tests on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475.aspx)
- [TestContext folders explained](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bhuvaneshwari/2012/02/24/testcontext-folders-explained/) written by Bhuvaneshwari K [MSFT]

(I believe that the second source has a mistake where the location of the `TestRunResultsDirectory` and `TestResultsDirectory` are swapped.)

When Visual Studio executes tests several folders are created.

**Base folder**

The test base folder is named using this template:

```
TestResults\Deploy_<user name> <timestamp>
```

If you specify setup and cleanup scripts in a `.testsettings` file, this folder contains those scripts. The `.testsettings` file also allows you to change the name of the folder.

**Out folder**

The base folder contains a folder named `Out`. The `Out` folder is the actual deployment folder, to which assemblies and other deployment files are copied when the test run starts.

If you need to refer to any of your deployed files, you should be using this folder.

**In folder**

Code-coverage results and certain other test results are stored in the folder named `In` located in the base folder.

If you add a file to the test result using the `TestContext.AddResult()` method, the file should be stored in this folder. (I haven't verified this claim myself as test results are stored when using Microsoft Test Manager and during TFS build; not when running tests in Visual Studio.)

**In\<machine name> folder**

A machine specific folder is created as a subfolder of the `In` folder. If you need to create temp files during the test run, you should be using this folder.

Here is a table that explains how `TestContext` properties map to the folders described above:

```
Property                               | Value
---------------------------------------+---------------------------
TestRunDirectory                       | Base folder
DeploymentDirectory                    | Out folder
ResultsDirectory, TestResultsDirectory | In folder
TestRunResultsDirectory                | Machine specific In folder
```

If all tests are successful then the folders are deleted by default. To change this behavior you can add a `.runsettings` file to your solution with the following contents:

```
<RunSettings>
    <MSTest>
        <DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>False</DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>
    </MSTest>
 </RunSettings>
```

To actually use this `.runsettings` file you will have to use the following menu selection in Visual Studio 2015: **Test** > **Test Settings** > **Select Test Settings File**. If you are using the ReSharper unit test runner then the settings are set in **Tools** > **Unit Testing** > **MsTest** in the ReSharper Options dialog box.

> [...] if I were to test file I/O would any of those be OK if I wanted to create a temporary *lorem ipsum* file?

Yes, you should use `TestRunResultsDirectory` for temporary files. Actually, I think you should be able to use any of these folders when unit testing inside Visual Studio. However, when doing remote tests and collecting diagnostics data it may be important to use this folder.

---

I have been thinking about the `In` and `Out` names which I find confusing. However, if you assume the perspective of a test controller it makes sense that tests are deployed to `Out` (test controller output) and when the tests are complete the results are collected from the `In` folder (test controller input). This is pure speculation on my part, of course.